# Jenkins multijob that runs selected job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I was wondering, is it possible to have for instance a jenkins multijob that contains a "job" select input parameter ?

I want to create a multijob that  :

1 - run a job A

2 - run the selected job (for instance "Hello_world")

3 - run job B

Answer (score 0):

There is a flexi publish plugin where you can control the post build steps based on the conditions, we use it for similar purpose and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Build Flow Plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin).
You can have it either receive the job name as a parameter (can also be a choice parameter to allow selecting options from a list), and run the jobs via the Flow DSL (Groovy). An example from the plugins doc: build("job1", parent_param1: params["param1"]), you could use a $DYNAMIC_JOB_NAME parameter as the job to run.

Answer (score 0):

Use **groovy scripts** with **multijob plugin** to select and disable specific jobs.

In jenkins you can find "execute system groovy script" option.